# Collecting Windows CPU Utilization from WMI Raw Counters

Tags: windows, wmi

I want to send a counter (incrementing number) of cpu utilization to a monitoring system. The monitoring system handles deltas for me, so in order to avoid gaps between the observation I want to preserve the counter and not send the delta value itself. I am currently doing the following which generally works, but there are occasional random spikes of CPU which don't make sense:

In a loop over each core:

```
used += v.Timestamp_Sys100NS - v.PercentIdleTime
num++ //To count the cores
```

And then:

```
cpu := used / 1e5 / num
```

As I said the above formula *seems* to be accurate from the monitoring systems derived deltas, except for the crazy spikes:

Derived:
[image]

Raw Counter:
[image]

Can anyone explain these spikes and/or suggest a way to avoid them?